# Indentation with "#." start of paragraph

Tags: vim, restructuredtext

When I type "1. blah blah blah" VIM recognizes the "1." prefix and it indents the rest of the paragraph tidy.

I would like to configure VIM to do the same thing with "#." literal prefix, since ReST files autonumbers the paragraphs when started with "#.".

Help!.

Comment: You might get answers more quickly at [Vi.SE](http://vi.stackexchange.com/)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is controlled by the `'formatlistpat'` option. From its `:help 'formatlistpat'`:

> A pattern that is used to recognize a list header.  This is used for
>     the "n" flag in 'formatoptions'.

So, you just need to add a branch for `#.` to it in your `~/.vimrc`, e.g. like this (using `:let` instead of `:set` to avoid the escaping of all the backslashes):

```
let &formatlistpat = '^\s*\%(\d\+\|#\)[\]:.)}\t ]\s*'
```

Additionally, you of course need to have the `n` flag in `'formatoptions'`:

```
setlocal formatoptions+=n
```

Comment: I am doing this in my ".vimrc": "autocmd BufRead,BufNewFile *.rst let &formatlistpat = '^\s*\%(\d\+\|#\)[\]:.)}\t ]\s*'". It doesn't work

Comment: Has the value been applied? You can check with `:verbose setl formatlistpat?`. To see the effect, try reformatting such lines with `gq`.

Comment: Yes, the ```:verbose``` shows the correct value, ```Last set from ~/.vimrc```. Looks good. But it doesn't work, neither while typing neither when reformating with ```gq```.

Comment: Doing ```:verbose setl formatoptions?``` I see ```formatoptions=tcq - Last set from /usr/share/vim/vim72/debian.vim```. No ```n``` anywhere.

Comment: Adding ```n``` to ```formatoptions``` solves the issue. Thanks!.